# Python vs Javascript execution time

Tags: javascript, python

I tried solving Maximum Subarray using both Javascript(Node.js) and Python, with brute force algorithm. Here's my code:

Using python:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

arr = [randint(-1000,1000) for i in range(1000)]

def bruteForce(a):
  l = len(a)
  max = 0
  for i in range(l):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(i, l):
      sum += a[j]
      if(sum > max):
        max = sum
  return max

start = datetime.now()
bruteForce(arr)
end = datetime.now()

print(format(end-start))
```

And Javascript:

```
function randInt(start, end) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1))
}

var arr = Array(1000).fill(randInt(-1000, 1000))

function bruteForce(arr) {
    var max = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var sum = 0
        for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            sum += arr[j]
            max = Math.max(max, sum)
        }
    }
    return max
}

var start = performance.now()
bruteForce(arr)
var end = performance.now()
console.log(end - start)
```

Javascript got a result of about 0.187 seconds, while python got 4.75s - about 25 times slower.
Does my code not optimized or python is really that slower than javascript?

Comment: properly structured JS is blisteringly fast when run in modern browsers. Perhaps one day just-in-time bytecode compilation by browsers will be efficiently applied to Python but it will have a lot of catching up to do. I once re-worked million-loop JS functions in C and the run times were very close - browsers are particularly efficient for processing repetitions such as loops where only one or two variable change. There's interesting background material here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/a-crash-course-in-just-in-time-jit-compilers/

Comment: @general-grievance, what was the time for the JS? of course different user systems will vary, it's the comparison that matters. Would be interesting to see how different set ups compare.

Comment: On my computer they both take approximately 0.3s

Comment: @DavePritlove True. Testing on [TIO](https://tio.run): Python: ~0.1s, and JS 0.07-0.08 s after removing all the output code. So, slower, just not by a factor of 25.

Comment: @general-grievance, yes, that's pretty close. Thanks.

Comment: JS - 2.011249989271164,
Py - 0:00:00.014953,
MacBook Pro M1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python is not per se slower than Javascript, it depends on the implementation.
Here the results comparing node and PyPy which also uses [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation):

```
> /pypy39/python brute.py
109.8594 ms N= 10000 result= 73682
> node brute.js
167.4442000091076 ms N= 10000 result= 67495
```

So we could even say "python is somewhat faster" ...
And if we use [Cython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython), with a few type-hints, it will be again a lot faster - actual full C speed:

```
> cythonize -a -i brutec.pyx
> python -c "import brutec"
69.28919999999998 ms N= 10000 result= 52040
```

---

To make the comparison reasonable, I fixed a few issues in your scripts:

- Fix: the js script filled an array with all the same values from a single random
- Does the same basic kind of looping in Python - instead of using the range iterator (otherwise its a little slower)
- Use the same time format and increase the array length to 10000 - otherwise the times are too small regarding resolution and thread switching jitter

Python code:

```
from time import perf_counter as clock
from random import randint

N = 10000
arr = [randint(-1000,1000) for i in range(N)]

def bruteForce(a):
  l = len(a)
  max = 0
  i = 0
  while i < l:
    sum = 0
    j = i
    while j < l:
      sum += a[j]
      if sum > max:
        max = sum
      j += 1
    i += 1
  return max

start = clock()
r = bruteForce(arr)
end = clock()
print((end - start) * 1000, 'ms', 'N=', N, 'result=', r)
##print(arr[:10])
```

JS code:

```
var start = -1000, end = 1000, N=10000
var arr = Array.from({length: N}, 
    () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1) + start))

function bruteForce(arr) {
    var max = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var sum = 0
        for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            sum += arr[j];
            max = Math.max(max, sum)
            //~ if (sum > max) max = sum;
        }
    }
    return max
}

var start = performance.now()
r = bruteForce(arr)
var end = performance.now()
console.log(end - start, 'ms', 'N=', N, 'result=', r)
//~ console.log(arr.slice(0, 10))
```

Code for Cython (or Python), enriched with a few type-hints:

```
import cython
from time import perf_counter as clock
from random import randint

N = 10000
arr = [randint(-1000,1000) for i in range(N)]

def bruteForce(arr):
  l: cython.int = len(arr)
  assert l <= 10000
  a: cython.int[10000] = arr  # copies mem from Python array
  max: cython.int = 0
  i: cython.int = 0
  while i < l:
    sum: cython.int = 0
    j: cython.int = i
    while j < l:
      sum += a[j]
      if sum > max:
        max = sum
      j += 1
    i += 1
  return max

start = clock()
r = bruteForce(arr)
end = clock()
print((end - start) * 1000, 'ms', 'N=', N, 'result=', r)
##print(arr[:10])
```

---

(Done on a slow notebook)

Comment: Py took 2825.7724170107394 ms N= 10000 result= 71565, JS took 39.68283399939537 ms N= 10000 result= 49005

Comment: Here are my results on virtual machine:


    ~# node --version
    v10.19.0
    
    ~# python3 --version
    Python 3.8.10
    
    ~# python3 test.py
    11107.16739995405 ms N= 10000 result= 81061
    
    ~# node test.js
    249.11676907539368 'ms' 'N=' 10000 'result=' 137303

Comment: Nobody uses PyPi because _of_ the implementation differences mean it is not compatible 100%.